# Install Extension via ZIP in TYPO3 composer installation

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I have a TYPO3 composer installation.There is an extension 'indexed-search-autocomplete' that is not installable via composer, because composer cannot find a stable version, but is available as stable version for my TYPO3 version  as ZIP and from TER on typo3.org.

Is there any clean way to get this extension to the system without composer?

I am grateful for any hint or link.

Comment: You can require the git repository directly: https://github.com/ingeniumdesign/indexed_search_autocomplete
See also: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: Just saw: The extension is on packagist, just not linked from the extension's page: https://github.com/ingeniumdesign/indexed_search_autocomplete#installation-using-composer

Answer (score 3):

## Simplyfied answer for that exact extension

As @hakre pointed out in a comment, if the package is registered on packagist you can (of course) always point to a commit on a published branch. So just

```
> composer req id/indexed-search-autocomplete dev-master#48d764d
```

## Original general solution:

You can point composer to the git repository at https://github.com/ingeniumdesign/indexed_search_autocomplete and require a specific commit, if a package is not available on packagist.

Add a repository entry to your projects `composer.json` like:

```
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ingeniumdesign/indexed_search_autocomplete"
    }
    ],
```

and then require e.g. `dev-master#48d764d` to let composer install that specific commit.

While [there are solutions to add extensions as payload to your composer project](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/12.4/en-us/MigrateToComposer/MigrationSteps.html#include-individual-extensions-like-site-packages), as long as the code is available publicly they should be avoided to ease maintenance.

Further steps to ease maintainability in the long run:

1. you can always ask the current maintainer to add version tags (which takes minutes), and to add a packagist.org auto-integration (which only needs to be configured once, and takes minutes), that way composer would find versions
2. if you make adaptions, you can do so via GitHub forks and create a PR which allows your solution to be used by others and you can easily add such patches to a composer project via [composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have the extension in the system now. 
I did not know that yet, again learned something about TYPO3 and composer.

Comment: The current maintainer publishes versions on packagist already: https://packagist.org/packages/id/indexed-search-autocomplete - it is also in the projects read-me file.

Comment: @hakre Updated the further step 1 accordingly for clarification. Alas, they don't publish versions, but only two branches. Thus, trying to require anything while on normal stability mode will result in no match.

Comment: @NextThursday: Yes, that's correct there aren't any tags, but IIRC it is like you answered originally (instead of version use the git revision/sha1 hash), you just do not need to add the VCS repository. I should have commented that earlier already, sorry for the really short comment. /edit: And yes, the recommendation the project uses tags remains spot on, good fix suggestion.

Comment: @hakre :O you are absolutely right. What a strange situation.